# presenceがtrueかfalseか知る方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

モデルのバリデーションで

```
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo, presence: true
end
```

となっていた場合、必須項目であることをフォームに表示させたいと思っています。
メタプログラミング的にモデルに`presence`が`true`か`false`問い合わせる方法はありませんか？

### 追記

考慮漏れしていたのですが
`validates :foo, presence: true, if: -> { false }`
とifを使ったパターンが抜けてしまっていました。できればこれにも対応したいです。
（ifオプションがtrueかfalseか知る方法がわかればいけそうな気が...）

いけました。

`.options[:if]`にProcが入っているので、
`.options[:if].call`でifオプションの結果が取得できました。

だたしやはり、
`if: :admin?`のパターンはシンボルが入っているので`.call`できないですね...

Answer (score 4):

`validators_on`を利用して以下のように判定する方法はいかがでしょうか。

```
# presence: trueが設定されている場合、trueが返る
Hoge.validators_on(:foo).any? { |_| _.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator) }
```

参考: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validators_on

Comment: 前提条件が変わって（質問の内容が変わって）しまって申し訳ないのですが `validates :foo, presence: true, if: -> { false }`でも`true`になってしまうようです。できればこのパターンも考慮したいです。

Answer (score 4):

こういうヘルパーメソッドを作ると便利かもしれません。

```
def required_field?(obj, attribute)
  obj.class.validators_on(attribute).map(&:class).include?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)
end

<% if required_field?(@user, :email) %>
  <span class="required">必須</span>
<% end %>
```

### 追記

> `validates :foo, presence: true, if: -> { false }` でもtrueになってしまうようです。できればこのパターンも考慮したいです。
>
> `.options[:if].call`でifオプションの結果が取得できました。

うーん、ifが指定された場合は、「ある程度」なら対応できるかもしれませんが、完璧を目指すのは難しそうです。

ifにはいろいろな指定方法があります。

```
# シンボルを使う
validates :name, presence: true, if: :admin?
# 文字列を使う
validates :name, presence: true, if: "admin?"
# 関連先のオブジェクトを参照する
validates :name, presence: true, if: -> { self.company.present? }
```

さらに、ifと逆パターンのunlessオプションや、`on: :create`、`on: :update`といった、onオプションもあります。
こういったケースにすべて対応させようと思うとかなり面倒なロジックが必要になりそうです。

そもそもifやunlessを使うと、オブジェクトの状態（条件）によって必須かどうかも変わるので、フォームを表示した時点では必須かどうか決定できない場合もあります。
（例：フォームの管理者チェックボックスにチェックを入れた場合のみ名前が必須、等）

要件によっては「`.options[:if].call` で十分」ということもあるかもしれませんが、万能ではないという点に留意された方が良いと思います。

参考：[5 条件付きバリデーション](http://railsguides.jp/active_record_validations.html#%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E3%83%90%E3%83%AA%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)

Comment: 前提条件が変わって（質問の内容が変わって）しまって申し訳ないのですが `validates :foo, presence: true, if: -> { false }`でも`true`になってしまうようです。できればこのパターンも考慮したいです。

Comment: たしかに :admin?の場合はシンボルが入っていたので厳しそうです...

Answer (score 0):

ちょっとズレますが情報提供的に。

ActiveModelのバリデーションの一部をHTMLに反映する(例: `validates presence: true` なら `required="required"` を付ける)ことによってHTML5のクライアントサイドバリデーションを行なわせる  [amatsuda/html5_validators](https://github.com/amatsuda/html5_validators) なんてのもあります。